# How to continue standart Asp.net Mvc - Application Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I handled all error messages if my mvc application running in Release Mode ( Publish mode )

But when I'm working in debug mode, I can't see standart mvc application error page.

Because it's redirecting to Error.cshtml which is located in shared folder.

How can I see(or redirect maybe?) standart mvc error page ?

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once RedundantAssignment
        // ReSharper disable once ConvertToConstant.Local
        bool isCustomErrorEnabled = false;
```

--#if(!DEBUG)
            isCustomErrorEnabled = true;
--#endif

```
        // ReSharper disable once ConditionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse
        if (isCustomErrorEnabled) //Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled
        {
            ShowCustomErrorPage(Server.GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            //in this line, I want to continue to show standart 
            // application error page which has error message and stack trace
        }

    }
```

UPDATE - Here is my Web.Config file;

```
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Home/OldLink" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <!-- RemoteOnly : Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is the default value. -->
</customErrors>
```

Comment: See webconfig  and search custom error mode

Comment: Ramesh, thank you for your answer. But I'm ignoring that line in app.config by "#if(!DEBUG)" in the code...

Answer (score 0):

MVC 4 Default support to handle error with HandleError attribute is redirecting you to Error.cshtml.

Just update your web.config with `customErrors mode="off"`